# About Corrupted LM35 IC and Arduino port problem

Tags: arduino-uno, temperature-sensor, port-mapping, lm35

I have one Arduino Uno which was **working fine** by below circuit([link](https://github.com/Startup-Data/UN-Hakim-PCR/edit/main/Arduino/Temperature)):
[image]

But when I have connected the new bought the **LM35 Ic** by the below connection:

[image]

The Arduino UNO don't **be recognized** by the my Ubuntu OS as you can see below:

[image]

And by **removing the LM35 connections**, the Arduino don't be recognized again. I have damaged **two Arduino Uno board** by **this mistake** and ...

So I don't know why this happened and for repairing the damaged circuits I hope find out **which part of the Arduino circuit** are probably damaged?

Thanks.

Comment: Ttyusb? Sounds like you're using cheap Chinese clones. Good luck with that...

Comment: Can you be specific regarding which LM35 variant and which pin you connected it to? Have you tried a standalone circuit?

Comment: @Dave_Newton, I can see the **??cxz LM35 DZ** on the IC which i don't know what is the two `??` character on the IC, but I googled it and i guess it is [this kind](https://sites.google.com/a/uu.tapdoanprime.com/w42/Precision-Celsjusza-Temperatury-Czujniki-LM35-LM35DZ-TO92-DO-92), I found the all `lm35 DZ` types pins are the same and my circuit connections is right ( based of [this datasheet](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/321/LM35DZ-pdf.php)).

Comment: @Dave_Newton,  For the third part of your question, I used the `LM35 DZ type` on the main circuit with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6FTQ.jpg) shematic (like the above)

Comment: @sosa FYI if you use `@` somebody with something other than what the autocomplete provides there's no notification. This isn't a schematic--I can't tell what pin you've hooked the LM35 to. It's unlikely the issue is caused by the LM35 itself; have you tried a circuit with *just* the LM35 as a sanity check?