# My Arduino don't show port but is working

Tags: stm32, upload

I have some problem with **Arduino uno** and asked [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/84593/about-corrupted-lm35-ic-and-arduino-port-problem?noredirect=1#comment190078_84593), so I have tried to work by my STM32F103C8 as alternative board, and solved my problem by this question:

[Arduino Port Not detected and can not run it as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345632/arduino-port-not-detected-and-can-not-run-it-as-root/1345851#1345851)

But now I as seeing that the Arduino port again is not acceptable but I can upload the codes into the STM32F103C8 board, so I asked why this happen ?

[image]
Note : I have seen [this post](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/akarsh98/using-a-stm32-like-an-arduino-tutorial-stm32f103c8-1073cb) which the STm32F103C8 board have some port on Arduino IDE (as you can see below ):

[image]

**Update:**

I have seen The below post about the same problem as you can see below:

[Can't open serial monitor using ST Link and STM32F103C8](https://www.stm32duino.com/viewtopic.php?t=90)

But, based of the last part of above post,which is shown below,
I don't get have could i have enable the serial port connection for the STM32f103C8 Board:

> I did everything as it was described in tutorial, flashing bootloader
> was succes, everything went ok, but windows still can't recognize it.
> I am thinking that maybe it is problem with that resistor and maybe i
> have to mod it... I think I will be sticking to ST-Link for uploading
> codes and USB-UART for serial. But thanks for help
>
> And one more question, can you tell me how to reset my Blue Pill to
> factory bootloader (how to delete stm32 bootloader that I installed)

Thank.

Comment: it doesn't work. only the tool reports a wrong result

Comment: Is there a default that it tries to transmit the sketch to if no ports are selected?

Answer (score 1):

The STM32F103C8 has a native USB interface. You will only ever see a CDC/ACM (USB UART emulation) interface if you actively run code that implements a CDC/ACM interface.

The bootloader is separate to your code. I don't know what protocol the bootloader for your board uses, but it may not even have a CDC/ACM interface to it.

**In short: it doesn't have a port because you haven't programmed it to have a port, and the code uploading doesn't use a port, so doesn't care.**

Comment: Thanks, but was is the means of **/dev/2** on the Arduino IDE result which shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOhxB.png)?!

Comment: It'll be something specific to dfu-util. Btw, dfu is a custom protocol that has no serial or anything like it.

Comment: So You are saying, For enabling the port option in Arduino IDE, I must burn some boatloader to the STM32f103c8 board by Arduino IDE or other software?

Comment: No, you just write a sketch that uses the usb serial.